# How to I get query strings of previous URL?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a query strings from previous URL in Laravel. My app is similar to Formspree where users can submit a form using and it get send to my website through POST method.

Here is a form hosted on external website

```html
<!-- https://user-website.com/?ref=53saf2 -->

<form action="https://localhost:8080/s/FORM_KEY" method="POST">
   <input type="email" name="email">
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I want to get capture **?ref=53saf2** in my Laravel controller.

I've tried

```
$request->headers->get('referer');

URL::previous();

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

None of it can capture ?ref.

My API route is

```
Route::post('s/{FORM_KEY}', [Controllers\SubmissionController::class, 'processForm']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store query string in service provider in a session

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can't as the form will be hosted in 3rd party external websites.